# Get all sub-subdirectories with same name

Tags: python, path

this is probably a dup but I couldn't find a suitable answer anyway.

I have a folder organized like this:

```
user $ pwd
/Users/user/project
user $ ls
dirA dirB dirC dirD dirPPPSN dirCH23
```

and in each one of the `dirX` there is a subfolder named CT (I am sure that the folder is present in all directories and they all share the same name.

How can I retrieve the list of paths `project/dirA/CT/`, `project/dirB/CT/,` ...?

I need this because I have to call `dicom2nifti` on all the subdirectories.

Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

base_dir = '/Users/user/project'  # your base dir path

target_sub_dir_name = 'CT'

ct_paths = []

# walk subdirs under base_dir
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    if dirs and target_sub_dir_name in dirs:
        ct_paths.append(os.path.join(root, target_sub_dir_name))

print(ct_paths)
```